# Problems importing data file

Tags: import, csv-format

I'm having trouble importing a CSV file.

The CSV file doesn't have simple dimensions, some rows may have many more columns than others.

From my imported file I cannot access the `importeddata` part specification below the second level.

Is there a better format to use?

```
info = {{{"Start", {4, 4, 5}, {0, 0, -1}, 
     1715}, {"End", {4, 4, -95}, {0, 0, -1}, 
     1715}}, {{"Start", {4, 4, 5}, {0, 0, -1}, 
     1715}, {"Process 2", {1, 4, 5}, {0, 0, -1}, 
     1715}, {"End", {1, 4, 5}, {0, 0, -1}, 
     1715}}, {{"Start", {4, 4, 5}, {0, 0, -1}, 
     1715}, {"Process 5", {4, 6, -95}, {0, 0, -1}, 
     115}, {"End", {3, 4, -9}, {0, 0, -1}, 1005}}};


Export["info.csv", info];
importdata = Import["info.csv", "CSV"];

(*this works *) 
info[[1]][[1]][[2]][[2]]
(*this doesn't*) 
importdata[[1]][[1]][[2]]
(*but this does *) 
importdata[[1]][[1]]
```

Comment: `importdata = Map[ToExpression] @ Import["info.csv","CSV"]`

Comment: Your data isn't a simple 2D array, so the exporter just made every line a string I believe.  If you have a choice of output formats, for this type of data JSON is perfect.  Use `Export["info.json", info, "RawJSON"]` and `importdata = Import["info.json", "RawJSON"]` and the data round trips perfectly.

Comment: if you don't need to share the data with other programs, another option is to use `Put/Get`:  `info >> "file.m"`   `importdata=Get["file.m"]`  will guarantee exactly the same in as out.